# How to neutralize an inherited Transform?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a complex `DataTemplate` for an item which contains a `Popup` (which replaced a previously used `ToolTip` btw). For one use case (appart of 3 others) the `DataTemplate` is used within an `ItemsControl` which itself can be scaled from 25% to 400% by the use of a `ScaleTransform`.
Now the (new) `PopUp` is also scaled (but the `ToolTip` wasn't) and I don't want this to happen.

For some reason only a scale transform seems to be propagated, a rotation transform is not:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="4"/>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ToggleButton Name="btn1" Content="btn1" ToolTip="hello1" Padding="5"/>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn1}" StaysOpen="True">
            <TextBlock Background="Lime" Padding="10" Text="pop1!"/>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="25"/>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ToggleButton Name="btn2" Content="btn2" ToolTip="hello2" Padding="5"/>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn2}" StaysOpen="True">
            <TextBlock Background="Lime" Padding="10" Text="pop2!"/>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="25"/>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="4"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ToggleButton Name="btn3" Content="btn3" ToolTip="hello3" Padding="5"/>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn3}" StaysOpen="True">
            <TextBlock Background="Lime" Padding="10" Text="pop3!"/>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1: Place the Popup outside of the influence of the LayoutTransform**

You could define the `Popup` outside of the transformed Grid and reference the `PlacementTarget` directly, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="25"/>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="4"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <ToggleButton Name="btn3" Content="btn3" ToolTip="hello3" Padding="5"/>
</Grid>
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn3}" StaysOpen="True" 
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn3}">
    <TextBlock Background="Lime" Padding="10" Text="pop3!"/>
</Popup>
```

**Option 2: Manually invert the LayoutTransform**

Or, if you want to keep you current layout, you could apply a "reverse" `Transformation` to the `Popup`:

```
<Popup.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.25"/>
</Popup.LayoutTransform>
```

But in that case, the better option would be to write a BindingConverter, that does that for you.

**Option 3: Automatically invert the LayoutTransform**

```
public class TransformInverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Transform transform = value as Transform;
        if (transform == null) 
            return Transform.Identity;
        return transform.Inverse;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="25"/>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="4"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <ToggleButton Name="btn3" Content="btn3" ToolTip="hello3" Padding="5"/>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn3}" StaysOpen="True"
           LayoutTransform="{Binding 
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, 
           Path=LayoutTransform, 
           Converter={StaticResource TransformInverter}}">
        <TextBlock Background="Lime" Padding="10" Text="pop3!"/>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

**Option 4: Traverse the VisualTree and undo all Transformations**

Now this one might be overkill in most cases, but maybe it's what you were looking for: Bind a Converter to the Popup itself, traverse the VisualTree, store all LayoutTransforms and cancel them out with inverse Transformations. This way has however one big flaw: It won't work if the Transformations can change over time. Long story short:

```
public class TransformResetter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        FrameworkElement transformedElement = value as FrameworkElement;
        if(transformedElement == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        Stack<Transform> transformations = new Stack<Transform>();

        FrameworkElement currentElement = transformedElement;
        while (currentElement != null)
        {
            currentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentElement) as FrameworkElement;
            if (currentElement != null)
            {
                if (currentElement.LayoutTransform != null)
                    transformations.Push(currentElement.LayoutTransform);
            }
        }

        TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
        while (transformations.Count > 0)
        {
            group.Children.Add(transformations.Pop());
        }

        return group.Inverse;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn3}" StaysOpen="True"
    LayoutTransform="{Binding 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
        Converter={StaticResource TransformResetter}}">
    <TextBlock Background="Lime" Padding="10" Text="pop3!"/>
</Popup>
```

**Option 5: Attach a Property that resets LayoutTransform on Opened**

Basically the same behavior as Option 4 that executes every time the Popup opens:

```
public class PopupOptions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CancelTransformationsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CancelTransformations", typeof(bool), typeof(PopupOptions), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnCancelTransformationsPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnCancelTransformationsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup element = (Popup)d;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            element.Opened += PopupChanged;
            RefreshTransform(element);
        }
        else
        {
            element.Opened -= PopupChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void PopupChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        RefreshTransform(sender as FrameworkElement);
    }

    private static void RefreshTransform(FrameworkElement transformedElement)
    {
        if (transformedElement == null)
            return;

        Stack<Transform> transformations = new Stack<Transform>();

        FrameworkElement currentElement = transformedElement;
        while (currentElement != null)
        {
            currentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentElement) as FrameworkElement;
            if (currentElement == null) continue;

            if (currentElement.LayoutTransform != null)
                if (!currentElement.LayoutTransform.Value.IsIdentity)
                    transformations.Push(currentElement.LayoutTransform);
        }

        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        while (transformations.Count > 0)
        {
            transformGroup.Children.Add(transformations.Pop());
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(transformGroup.Children[0].Value);

        transformedElement.LayoutTransform = (Transform)transformGroup.Inverse;
    }

    public static void SetCancelTransformations(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        if (!(element is Popup))
            throw new Exception("Nope!");

        element.SetValue(CancelTransformationsProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetCancelTransformations(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(CancelTransformationsProperty);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn3}" StaysOpen="True"
  yourNameSpace:PopupOptions.CancelTransformations="True">
    <TextBlock Background="Lime" Padding="10" Text="pop3!"/>
</Popup>
```

**Background Info**

The reason why `RotateTransform` is not applied is because `AllowsTransparency` is `false`. Without this, the Popup has to stay rectangular. If you set it to `true` the rotation will also be applied.

Comment: I could use any of the 3 options if I would know about the `Transform`. But as said the DataTemplate is globally used in the application, other DataTemplates use it within `ContentPresenter` to build even more complex DataTemplates. And such DataTemplate is then eventually placed inside a ListBox whose `ItemsPanel` has the ScaleTransform applied (and this happens in an external Window with limited life time).

Comment: There, all done. Added another option, now I'm out of Ideas so I hope this helps :)

Comment: Option 5 looks promising. BTW: Option 3 can be done without the converter by just extending the Binding Path to the `Inverse` property: `Path=LayoutTransform.Inverse`

Comment: Option 5 works, but has 2 problems: It crashes on `Debug.WriteLine` in DEBUG build when there is no transform in visual tree at all (easily fixable), and after having changed an outer Transform the popup always opens with wrong scaling once and on next open it looks correct. (.NET 4.6.1)